# UNUserNotificationCenter delegate methods not called in case of broadcast notification service but called when FCM messaging

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I am trying to handle push notification using FCM on IOS , I tested notifications using firebase cloud messaging and it is working fine (app receives notification in both background and foreground perfectly) , When trying to test using a service that send a broadcast notification , I get notification payload in `didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)` but all UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate never called .

the broadcast notification received on android app but not on IOS , Firebase project and android project on firebase are added first and the broadcast service tested on android then we added the IOS app to firebase , Is there any update on server can be added to support the IOS app?

I can't catch the problem if it from server or from the IOS app !

Anyone can help?

Comment: Did you notify delegate like that? `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self`

Comment: yes , it is working fine from cloud message test on firebase

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you posted the payload of receiving notifications, Make sure the payload **does not include** `content-available = 1` and **include** `alert`.